# USB security token (not storage) from bank: VirtualBox does not see it

Tags: usb, virtualbox

On Mac I inserted this USB key into Apple Cinema Display with USB port (my MacBook Pro only has USB-C ports) and it worked with VirtualBox. Now I trying to connect this USB key to the virtual machine with Windows on another host machine, with Linux. On the screenshot - log from `dmesg`, looks like my Ubuntu 16.04.4 i386 see it, but VirtualBox from repository not. Also I installed `virtualbox-ext-pack` that required for USB 2.

[image: screenshot dmesg virtualbox usb no device available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your username in the `vboxusers` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
```

Logout login and it should be good.

See:

- [How to add users to vboxusers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377778/how-to-add-users-to-vboxusers)